# Doubts about Quantum Physics: Collision by electrons

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I have some doubts about the energy level diagram for excitation/de-excitation of electrons when bombarded by other electrons.
Does the "energy levels" correspond to the shells of the atom? If so, why only the electrons in n=1 (ground state) get excited by collision? How about electrons in the 2nd, 3rd shells etc?

I was also studying X-ray emission, and according to my lecture notes, the electron from the innermost-shell of the target metal atom must be knocked out of the atom completely (to infinity potential) for the outer-shell electrons move down, therefore releasing X-ray photons. However, I do not understand why the electrons cannot simply excite and de-excite as electrons from gases do.

Help appreciated. Thank you！

Comment: For atoms with enough electrons, you do get to the point where an empty state in the 2nd shell may result in an x-ray being emitted. Hence the difference between K shell and L shell x-rays.

Answer (score 1):

The electron shells correspond to the *principal energy states*, with small corrections to the energy for different subshells or orbitals.

It is not true in general that only electrons in the ground state can be excited by collisions. The trajectory of an incoming electron depends on its energy and angle with respect to the nucleus.

Electrons are fermions, which means that they obey the Pauli exclusion principle, so only two electrons can be found in each orbital. Electrons in a higher energy state cannot spontaneously decay if all lower energy orbitals are already occupied.